# what is main purpose of meta tag while creating web application other than search engine if any?

Tags: html, web

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://wellso.in/WellSoWebsite/Blogs/Highheelsdisadvantages_10.html"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://wellso.in/WellSoWebsite/img/blog/highheels.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="If you wear high heels read this"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="wellso.in"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Wearing high heels regularly can lead to premature osteoarthritis" />
```

What this meta property signify?

Comment: Those are `og` meta tags, short for "open graph".  Those are primarily used for Facebook and Twitter (and similar) so that when someone pastes in a url from your website the cool image shows up instead of just the url string.  Meta tags in general are a much larger category.

Comment: thanks man @nurdyguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These meta tags that you mentioned are for facebook crawler to read properties about your page. To know about all the uses of meta tags, checkout [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_meta_tags.htm)

Comment: You're welcome @shaldark and welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer worked for you, please mark it as correct. Thanks.